# Some times my server not ping by my web-api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Sometimes my server not ping by my web-API 
I make web-API that will communicate with my server and return data as I request.
for that first request check that is the server is a ping or not then it will proceed the request.

but from last two or three days that ping is throwing timeout, so what're the reasons for it??

Comment: Maybe check the server error logs...maybe the server cannot proceed your request, so it doesn't send a message back to your api

Comment: where do i check server log? and it true that server not proceed the request but why??

Comment: On the server itself. Is your Server Windows or Linux based?

Comment: Maybe you can add some code how u trying to ping the server? The Code may be also The problem

Comment: Server is windows base and code work perfect if its not then stop getting work from day one i face this problem from last days

Comment: Then check the the eventviewer in windows to check if the IIS is getting some errors